# How to specify the location for the unit test results in VS 2010?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I use VS2010 for unit testing.  Does anyone know how to specify the location of where VS 2010 put its TestResults?  By default it put a TestResults folder in the solution folder, I'd like to move it out somewhere else.

Thanks,
Ray.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible to control from within the IDE, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vststest/thread/4ff650e1-a99a-4bd4-8311-6007f2a6e16e.

However, if you can use MSTEST.EXE from the commandline, it will use the current folder to generate the TestResults folder in.

**Update:**

Found this in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/10/24/test-agent-test-controller-and-mstest-faq.aspx:

> *How to customize the default deployment directory?*
>
> You can change the default deployment folder by editing the test settings file in the XML editor:

```
<Deployment userDeploymentRoot="C:\TestResults" useDefaultDeploymentRoot ="false" />
```

> Note that ,if the test settings is modified by XML edit (instead of using the default editor) VS need to be closed and reopened ( since the editing is done in XML , the changes will not be updated in the loaded settings.)

Best regards,
Marco Kroonwijk

Comment: Where is this done exactly?  Which file?  I was assuming it was in the solution, but the solution for VS 2010 isn't XML.

Comment: Nevermind, I apparently had deleted the local.testsettings file from my solution somewhere along the way.  Just had to add a new one to the solution items.

Comment: Just a warning about userDeploymentRoot - If you set a relative path this property evaluates the full path with the current directory of compiler. If you open your solution from explorer this will evaluate to the solution folder all good) but if you open the IDE and then your project, this path evaluates to the compiler exe somewhere in Program files. Just thought I would share so no one gets mislead by this.

Comment: One MAJOR thing to point out that I just spent hours on: IF you use the commandline /resultsfile switch when trying to use this setting in the settings file, then the deployment settings DON'T work.  Other settings in the settings file seem to work fine and all the other commandline switches I tried seem to not interfere, but that /resultsfile in particular must override that deployment line in the settings file.

Answer (score 0):

MSTest.exe will generate results in the current folder as kroonwijk states, but you can override that with the /resultsfile command line switch by specifying the output filename in a different folder, it will also deploy a subfolder with the test files to the same location.

For example "/resultsfile:c:\TestResults\mstestreport.trx" will override the default deployment folder and also override anything that is in the `<deployment>` tag in the settings file.