# Ways to increase Visual Studio productivity with excessive amounts of RAM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ram

Normally, I try to get visual studio and plugins to use minimal amount of RAM because my work systems often have 3-4 GB available and large C# projects.  Soon, I may have a desktop with either 16 or 32 GB of RAM.

What productivity options/plugins do you recommend using when RAM is less of a consideration?

Existing Environment:
Visual Studio 2010, ReSharper, NCrunch

Comment: I see that this question was already voted down.  Is this considered ambiguous or in the wrong stackexchange site?

Comment: Not constructive. Anyone can chime in with their favorite plugin. There is no "right answer", its very subjective. (IMO.)

Comment: @Mat, to claim that a question with no (single) right answer is not *constructive* is a gross misuse of the word constructive.  SO users can choose to close these questions if they like, but it's absurd to claim they're not constructive.

Comment: @Nate: that's the SE close reason used for "list-of-stuff" questions. I was not trying to start a semantic debate about the word "constructive" 5 months ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can move [TestResults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908235/how-to-specify-the-location-for-the-unit-test-results-in-vs-2010) and [Ncrunch workspace](http://wiki.ncrunch.net/workspaces.ashx) to ramdisk. Also you can move temp files and even whole project folder (or only bin & obj folders) to ramdisk.