# VS2012 Unit Tests: How to change the location of the TestResults folder

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have all my Unit Test project in a folder under my Solution Folder and would like to have the TestResults folder in the same folder as the Test projects instead in the solution directory.

I have found that this could be done via the test seeting file:
[How to specify the location for the unit test results in VS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908235/how-to-specify-the-location-for-the-unit-test-results-in-vs-2010)

but I also read, that with VS2012 you should no longer use tests settings files. Actually VS2012 does not create one.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 6):

To specify a different location for the "TestSettings" folder, add a `.runsettings` to your solution as explained in the Visual Studio documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx

My `.runsettings` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\Visual Studio Test Results</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

As far as I could tell, however, the ResultsDirectory location is not relative to the solution folder (like the example file from the doc suggests), but rather relative to the location of the `.runsettings` file itself. Also note that Visual Studio macros like `$(SolutionDir)` are not expanded here.
All in all, `.runsettings` files are not related to a particular project or solution.

The reason why they recommend using `.runsettings` files instead of `.testsettings` in newer version of Visual Studio is also found in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991.aspx

> If you use a **.testsettings** file, the MSTest test framework will be
>   used to run your tests. This runs more slowly and does not allow you
>   to run tests from third-party test frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a small RunSettings file which looks like

```
  <RunSettings>
     <RunConfiguration>
        <ResultsDirectory>e:\myResultsFolder</ResultsDirectory>
     </RunConfiguration>
  </RunSettings>
```

Select this setting file via top level menu Test->TestSettings->"Select Test Settings" before running your tests.

You can find more detail on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx.

Comment: Hi Patrick,I tried it, but the RunSettings file is ignored. The moment I start VS2012 the TestResults folder ist created in the SolutionsDir.